# How to match a whole word if a specific character exists in the word?

Tags: python, regex

What I would like to do is to match a whole word if it contain a certain character, say %. For example if I have "This i%s^ a %test" it would match the whole word "i%s^" and "%test".

What I have tried is for example `(?=\%)(.*?\s)*` that in my mind say "If matches % then grab its word until a space". What it lacks is if the word is at the end of the row, but instead it match the first occurrence and then matches everything until it occurs again. Do not understand why.

Comment: Maybe a pattern like `\S*%\S*` works for you?

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\S*%\S*
```

- `\S*`: match non-space characters 0 or more time
- `%`: match a single `%`
- `\S*`: match non-space characters 0 or more time

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSb61D/2).

Comment: Thank you! That works just as I want! Will mark as solved asap

Comment: @Salviati Use `[^%\s]*%\S*` instead to avoid extra backtracking.

Comment: Yes, it is better in terms of performance. I would also suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

No regex needed, really, just use `in`:

```
string = "This i%s^ a %test"

words = [word for word in string.split() if "%" in word]
print(words)
```

This yields

```
['i%s^', '%test']
```

And works even with multiple conditions:

```
words = [word for word in string.split() 
         if all(char in word for char in ["s", "%"])]
# ['i%s^', '%test']
```

Comment: I will use ```re.sub``` just to follow the standard I have up until now it have to be regex